# Message: Object of class CI_DB_oci8_result could not be converted to string

Tags: codeigniter-3

The `$user` contains a `CHAR` datatype from the database.

My error was:

> Message: Object of class CI_DB_oci8_result could not be converted to
>   string

This is my Code:

```
        $this->db->select('CONSULTATION_DATE,CONSULTATION_DESC,CONSULTATION_STATUS');
        $this->db->from('SCHEDULE_REQUEST');
        $this->db->where("STUDENT_ID= '". $user."'");
        $this->db->where("CONSULTATION_STATUS LIKE 'Accept'");
        $data['status']=$this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
    $this->db->select('CONSULTATION_DATE,CONSULTATION_DESC,CONSULTATION_STATUS');
    $this->db->from('SCHEDULE_REQUEST');
    $this->db->where("STUDENT_ID= '". $user."'");
    $this->db->where("CONSULTATION_STATUS LIKE 'Accept'");
    $result=$this->db->get();//data store as Object Array
```

**EDIT 01**

```
$this->db->select('CONSULTATION_DATE,CONSULTATION_DESC,CONSULTATION_STATUS');
$this->db->from('SCHEDULE_REQUEST');
$this->db->where("STUDENT_ID= '". $user."'");
$this->db->where("CONSULTATION_STATUS LIKE 'Accept'");
$result=$this->db->get();//data store as Object Array
$data['array'] = $result;
```

In View

```
foreach ( $array as $item )
{
    echo $item['table_filed'];
}
```

**EDIT 02**

In Model

```
public function get_data($user)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT CONSULTATION_DATE,CONSULTATION_DESC,CONSULTATION_STATUS FROM schedule_request WHERE STUDENT_ID= '$user' AND CONSULTATION_STATUS LIKE 'Accept' ");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

In Controller

```
$data['result'] = $this->Model_name->get_data($user);
$this->load->view("View_name",$data)
```

In View

```
foreach ($result as $item )
{
    echo $item['table_filed'];
}
```

Comment: How ca I output the value of it in the view folder?
This is my code in the view folder:
*
<?php  
foreach ($status->result() as $row1)  
{  
?>



<tr>  
<td><?php echo $row1->CONSULTATION_DATE;?></td> 
<td><?php echo $row1->CONSULTATION_DESC;?></td>
<td><?php echo $row1->CONSULTATION_STATUS;?></td>
</tr>


<?php } ?>
*

Comment: My error is the same as this:
Message: Object of class CI_DB_oci8_result could not be converted to string

Comment: thank you very much Sir Abdulla form your sharing of knowledge but sadly it didn't work. anyway i try to search for other way or create a new one. thanks again Sir Abdulla. more powers.